# probability problem explanation

Tags: probability

To enter a cereal competition, competitors have to choose the eight most important features of a new car, from a possible $12$ features, the list the eight in order of preference. Each cereal packet entry form contains space for five entries. A correct entry wins a  new car.

a) What is the probability that a woman wins a new car if she completes the entry form from one packet?

b) How many entry forms would she need to complete, each entry showing different arrangement, if the probability that she wins a car is to be at least $0.8$?

The answer given for part a) is $2.5 \times 10^{-7}$. I know it can be obtained from $\frac{5}{12P8}$. What I don't understand is why the $5$ is numerator instead of denominator?

Remark: There was a typo before, I mis-type eight as right. It was corrected.

Comment: a) Isn't this just $\frac 1{\binom {12} 5}$ (if I understand the problem right)

Comment: For b), you need $\frac 45 \cdot \binom{12}5$

Comment: There seems to be an assumption that the woman is guessing randomly, which is arguably not a good strategy if she's only filling out one form.

Answer (score 1):

Each entry form has room for $5$ different answers.

Each answer has probability:

$\qquad \dfrac{1}{12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5}$

So multiply that by $5$ to give the desired result: $\quad2.5 \times 10^{-7}$.

Comment: +1, and thanks for the head's up on my answer. Looks like I misread the OP due to typos. Will probably remove my answer so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: @Zimul8r Thanks. The question was not very clear, especially the pre-edited version. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I get the given result for a) only, if space for entries is 7.

First you have to choose the 7 correct features: $12 \choose 7$

Then you have calculate the possible orders of the 7 features: $7!$

The probablity is then $\frac{1}{{12 \choose 7} \cdot 7!}=\frac{1}{3,991,680}\approx 2.5 \cdot 10^{-7}$

greetings,

calculus